# Tell Typescript to look for problems in files in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VS Code has a "Go to Next Problem in Files" command, which can move to the next known TypeScript problem in any file.

My issue is that often no problems have yet been identified. They exist (if I run `tsc` manually it shows errors). How can I prompt TypeScript to scan the directory for errors, within VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Does your project contain `tsconfig.json` file? If not, run `tsc --init` in the terminal and the basic configuration will be set for your project.

Hence, You should config the project typescript based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `>Typescript: Restart TS Server` for restart the TS server in VSCode.

Sometimes, VSCode becomes so slow that it cannot correctly detect the status of a Typescript project